# Can I make a structured reference absolute in excel 07?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a table "A" with 2 columns "Foo" and "Bar". I have a formula with the structured reference A[Foo]. When I fill this formula horizontally I want the reference to stay A[Foo] but now, in the second column, the reference turns to A[Bar]. Is there a way to make this structured reference absolute?

It'd be shocking that this isn't supported if not.

Example Formula:

=A[Foo]

Drag that horizontally and Foo changes if the table has multiple columns

Comment: Could you give an example formula?

Comment: I added one. I can give you the exact formula from my sheet, but I think that illustrates my problem. Let me know.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. When I copy the formula horizontally the referenced column stays the same. Could you describe the exact steps that you do?

Comment: Does your table have multiple columns? In cell A1 I type Foo, in cell B1 I type Bar. I insert a table selecting A1:B1. I add value 1, 2 to Foo and Bar respectively. In A4 i enter the formula '=A[Foo]'. I drag formula to B4 and the formula changes to '=A[Bar]'

Comment: @excel-campus has the best answer to the posted problem despite not having the highest number of votes at this time... The formula you want is: =A[[Foo]:[Foo]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a difference between copying and dragging. Dragging is also called "filling" formulas. On [Microsoft's support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912) you will find the following explanation:

> **Moving, copying, and filling
>   structured references**
>
> All structured references remain the
>   same when you copy or move a formula
>   that uses a structured reference.
>
> When you fill a formula, fully
>   qualified structured references can
>   adjust the column specifiers like a
>   series as summarized in the following
>   table.

So it basically means that the behavior you see is by design. If you want the reference to be absolute you should copy the formula and not drag/"fill" it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately, unless I'm doing something wrong, even filling with CTRL adjusts the formulas like a series. Does it work for you? Looks like I'll just be copying.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pressing Ctrl or not. Just copy and paste the cell and you will the reference be the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can make the reference absolute by duplicating the reference to column as if it were a range.  Looks like the following:

A[[Foo]:[Foo]]

Put A[[Foo]:[Foo]] in your formula and drag across.  The reference will remain on the [Foo] column.  Note, you have to drag the formula.  Copy/paste won't work.

This also works if you want an absolute reference on a cell in the same row of the same table.  Assuming the formula is in the Table named "A", the following will anchor the cell in the same row of the formula.

A[@[Foo]:[Foo]]

There is an article and video on my site about this issue where I attempt to explain it clearly. :)

http://www.excelcampus.com/tips/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make the <kbd>Control</kbd>+`drag` idea work either. However, by selecting the original cell and the ones to be filled and using the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, fill right, shortcut did seem to copy without changing the structured references across columns.

Comment: This worked great for me. A formula of =COUNTIFS(Table1[Field1],TRUE,Table1[Field2],A1) adjusted the relative cell reference A1 properly (horizontally) and left the structured references as is, unadjusted.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you cannot make a structured reference (.ie - A[Foo]) absolute.  If you want to use absolute references in your formula, so you can use the fill handle, use the old method of absolute reference ($A$2 or $A2)

Example:

Table Name: DiscountPricing

```
    A       B           C                                   D
1   Item    Base Price  5%                                  10%


2   Pencil  $0.50       =[Base Price]-([Base Price]*        =[5%]-([5%]*
                        DiscountPricing[[#Headers],[5%]])   *DiscountPricing[[#Headers],[10%]])

3   Pen     $1          =$B3-($B3*                        =$B3-($B3*
                        *DiscountPricing[[#Headers],[5%]])  *DiscountPricing[[#Headers],[10%]])
```

See for additional info:
http://www.technicalcommunicationcenter.com/2011/05/31/how-to-use-structured-references-in-ms-excel/

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the Table name with an INDIRECT function like;

```
INDIRECT("Table Name[Column Heading]")
```

In your Case, `INDIRECT("A[Foo]")`

Now you can drag it horizontally and the column reference stays static !!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you hold down Ctrl while copying the formulas, it will remain static/absolute.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA101556861033.aspx

Comment: Hmm, well I had seen that link. It doesn't work for me though. I can manually copy and paste but I can't drag the columns horizontally. Have you verified this your self? I just wanna make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your still dragging/filling, aim for the bottom of the cell, not the corner.
Ross